# \enclosure without \makeletterclosing

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to make an enclosure to my CV (not the cover letter!) and I have so far only found the command \enclosure{CV}. But this command has to be combined with \makeletterclosing, which puts my name at the end of the CV where it doesn't belong.

```
\section{Hobbies}
\cvitem{}{Hiking, reading, gardening, swimming, kayaking, tennis}


\enclosure{CV --> this does not show unless I add \makeletterclosing}
\end{document}
```

Does someone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is best to provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem, rather than just code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You should just set this information as-is using the same style as what is used by `\enclosure`:

[image]

The above output is produced from the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) with the addition of

```
{\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: Some strange enclosure}

{\color{color2}\itshape Email: Some strange enclosure}
```

immediately before the start of the bibliography.